# Stylus / User Javascript & CSS or similar browser extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, css

I have both Stylus and User Javascript & CSS extensions in Chrome.  An Iframe container than I re-styled no longer obeys the styling which has remained unchanged in both extensions.  It had worked for several years and the site's CSS has remained unchanged. Neither extension apply it to the site anymore.  I haven't used it in a few months so I'm not sure what broke.  A Chrome update??

Has anyone had a similar issue or know how to get the styles to apply?

For example, I'm just changing the font-size to make it non-microscopic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the regex matching engine must have been updated.  It stopped matching the site even though the URL is unchanged.  Once I applied it to everything it worked.  I will continue to troubleshoot the URL regex matching out of curiosity.